# Pushing a commit to GitHub

Tags: c, libgit2

I've been trying to push a commit created with libgit2 to github for a while, I've managed to overcome quite a lot of the issues I was facing, but the "final" on is to actually push the commit, as currently it doesnt error, but also doesnt actually seem to work. So my code is something like (ive omitted all error checking for brevity):

```c
...
git_commit_create(...); // create the commit
...
git_remote_lookup(&remote, _repo, "origin");
git_remote_init_callbacks(&cbs, GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_VERSION);
cbs.credentials = my_git_cred_cb;
git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_PUSH, &cbs, NULL, NULL);
git_remote_add_push(_repo, "origin", "refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master");
git_push_options_init(&options, GIT_PUSH_OPTIONS_VERSION);
options.callbacks = cbs;
git_remote_upload(remote, null, &options);
git_remote_disconnect(remote);
git_remote_free(remote);
```

All these functions pass, and no error is returned, however, the commit hasnt been pushed. My guess is that my refspec (`refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`) is off - ive tried loads and loads of others but am just going in circles. Am i doing something totally wrong here, has anyone else used libgit2 to fully push a commit to a github repository? Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does Github have your commit? Can you pull it based on its SHA?

Comment: GitHub doesnt have any of the commits at all, its as if they werent pushed at all (but no error given). Git status shows: https://pastebin.com/mHkd2tKU

Comment: Try looking at the [documentation on the libgit2 website](https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/) for some examples of working code using the libgit2 libraries and see if you can gain any insight there.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use `git_remote_push` instead of connect, upload, etc.? What kind of credential does your callback create?

Comment: There is certainly no reason why i have used push, except maybe i assumed it was the "correct" path and went down that route. I thought (assumed) that i would have to create a push on the remote, then upload that that set of pushes? Honestly, im not sure (at all) what the correct flow is supposed to be.

The callback just returns my GH user/pass, pretty sure that part is fine as without i get a 401.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to `git_remote_push`. At the very least it will correctly update local refs, which you're currently missing.

Comment: Also, now that I look at it more closely, a possible error is you set the remote refspec config (by remote name) after looking up the remote object. Those config values might not be read again after you set them. I'd recommend passing the refspec to `git_remote_push` to rule that out.

Comment: Actually, it's right in the documentation for `git_remote_add_push`: No loaded remote instances will be affected.

Comment: OK, thats great! git_remote_push with the refspecs added seems to work, and the commits show up in github! Thanks loads! Im _sure_ i wouldnt have thought to try that other function.

I do have a quick question though - how come the files ive commited also still show up in the "git status" on the command line? I would have expected / hoped for it all be clean and done

Many thanks again! Was really going in circles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, thanks to Jason Haslam in the comments, Ive managed to figure it out, since libgit2 full examples seem a little thin on ground Im posting my own solution as an answer, it might help someone else. Ive omitted errors and obvious variable creation for brevity.

```c
// open reop
git_repository_open_(&repo, "path/to/repo");
// add commit
git_signature_now(&sig, "Name", "Email");
git_repository_index(&index, repo);
git_index_add_bypath(index, "some_test_file.txt");
git_index_write_tree(&tree_oid, index);
git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &tree_oid);
git_reference_name_to_id(&parent_oid, repo, "HEAD");
git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, &parent_oid);
git_commit_create(&oid_commit, repo, "HEAD", sig, sig, null, "commit message", tree, 1, &parent);
// ... free all created objects

// push to github
git_remote_lookup(&remote, repo, "origin");
git_remote_init_callbacks(&cbs, GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_VERSION);
cbs.credentials = &my_git_cred_cb;
git_push_options_init(&options, GIT_PUSH_OPTIONS_VERSION);
options.callbacks = cbs;

char *refspec_strings[] = {
    "HEAD:refs/heads/master",
};
git_strarray refspec_array = {
    refspec_strings,
    1,
};

git_remote_push(remote, &refspec_array, &options);
git_remote_upload(remote, null, &options);

git_repository_state_cleanup(repo); // not sure this is needed

char *pathspec_strings[] = {
    "HEAD",
};
git_strarray pathspec_array = {
    pathspec_strings,
    1,
};

git_reset_default(repo, null, &pathspec_array); // needed to reset to stop "git status" showing anything - not sure why it does
git_remote_disconnect(remote);
// ... free all created objects
```

The creditials callback is nice and simple:

```c
int my_git_cred_cb(git_cred **cred, const char *url, const char *username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload) {
    if ((allowed_types & GIT_CREDTYPE_USERPASS_PLAINTEXT) != 0) {
        return git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(cred, "gh_user", "gh_pass");
    } else {
        /* Some other kind of authentication was requested */
        return -1;
    }

    return 1; /* unable to provide authentication data */
}
```